# Swift Generic Function Without Explicit Declaration

Tags: swift, vapor

I am facing problem in creating a generic function that will handle all the requests I receive in Vapor. I hope someone can help me to fix this issue

```
func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        routes.get("localsetting", ":param") { request in
            let response: OutboundWrapper<LocalSettingsDO> = self.handleIncomingRequest(request: request, entity: .localSetting)
            return response
        }
        routes.get("client", ":param:") { request in
            let response: OutboundWrapper<ClientDO> = self.handleIncomingRequest(request: request, entity: .client)
            return response
        }
}
```

```
fileprivate func handleIncomingRequest<T: Content>(request: Request, entity: Entity) -> OutboundWrapper<T> {
        var outboundWrapper = OutboundWrapper<T>()
        
        switch entity {
        case .client:
            var domainObject = ClientDO()
            if let param = request.parameters.get("param") {
                outboundWrapper = OutboundWrapper(data: domainObject as! T)
            }
        case .localSetting:
            var domainObject = ApplicationLocalSettingsDO()
            if let param = request.parameters.get("param") {
                outboundWrapper = OutboundWrapper(data: domainObject as! T)
            }
        }
        return outboundWrapper
}
```

```
struct OutboundWrapper<T: Content>: Content {
    public dynamic var data: T? = nil
    
    public init() {}
    public init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

I feel that in this implementation, I missed out the purpose of generic as i need to explicitly cast my function return with `let response: OutboundWrapper<ClientDO>` for every entity function.

Is there a better way to improve this so that I can just call `self.handleIncomingRequest` ?

Comment: The only difference between the two cases of your `switch` is only that type of `domainObject`? And you are not using the `predicate` anywhere? Am I missing something? Or is this not the entire code?

Comment: @Sweeper hi Sweeper, yes you are right, basically the switch cases are just there to differentiate the domainObject that i need to pass to the OutboundWrapper. for the predicate, I didnt include this as that is not the main concern of the question. Hope I answered your question :)

Comment: I suggest that you should show more of the code in `handleIncomingRequest`. I wouldn't want to spend time writing an answer only for you to say "actually that wouldn't work for me because my actual code is like [...]"

Comment: The rest of the logic is to retrieve data from local DB and to filter only, nothing complex. I am still writing my function, so actually it is not completed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having an `Entity` parameter that you check, have the caller pass in a factory `() -> T`, that `handleIncomingRequest` uses to construct a `T`. This avoids all the `as! T` stuff.

```
fileprivate func handleIncomingRequest<T: Content>(request: Request, contentFactory: () -> T) -> OutboundWrapper<T> {

    var domainObject = contentFactory()
    if let param = request.parameters.get("param") {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ID == %i", param.convertToInt())

        // do something with predicate, perhaps (?)

        return OutboundWrapper(data: domainObject)
    }
    return OutboundWrapper()
}
```

Usage:

```
let response = self.handleIncomingRequest(request: request, contentFactory: LocalSettingsDO.init)
```

Alternatively, have a protocol that requires a parameterless initialiser:

```
protocol DomainObbject {
    init()

    // perhaps also:
    // func predicate(for param: String) -> NSPredicate
}

extension LocalSettingsDO: DomainObject {}
extension ClientDO: DomainObject {}
```

Then `handleIncomingRequest` can take a `T.Type`, and you can directly call the initialiser in the method:

```
fileprivate func handleIncomingRequest<T: Content & DomainObject>(request: Request, domainObjectType: T.Type) -> OutboundWrapper<T> {

    var domainObject = T()
    ...
}
```

Instead of passing `LocalSettingsDO.init`, you would pass `LocalSettingsDO.self`.

Comment: if there is different implementation of the predicate, I can check the domainObject by using `if domainObject is LocalSettingDO` or `if domainObject is ClientDO` yes? or is there any better way to do? But so far this one really teaches me new thing. Really appreciate it !

Comment: do you mind to elaborate more on how to switch the type in your alternative way?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Switching on the type wouldn't work. You can add a function to the `DomainObject` protocol that gives you a predicate though.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper, i will look into it. Really appreciate your help. Will experiment based on your codes. Thanks!